# Unknown process name- vImageConvert_AnyToAny - failed on beginBackgroundTask

Tags: swift, uigraphicscontext, uibackgroundtask

Hey So i am resizing my images on a background thread that keeps executing after the app entered the background with `beginBackgroundTask` along with some other code like so:

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
  let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
  let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        
  image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
  let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
  return newImage!
}
```

When I trigger the resize **and go back to the home screen** then I get a bunch of the following errors. **But if I let it run in the foreground it runs flawlessly.**

> [Unknown process name] vImageConvert_AnyToAny - failed width = 0 height = 1 dst component = 8bit integer dstLayout = ByteOrder32Little dstBytesPerRow = 0 src component = 8bit integer srcLayout = ByteOrderDefault srcBytesPerRow = 0

When I set a breakpoint I can't say for certain that my resize logic is spitting out these errors but it has to be because `vImageConvert_AnyToAny` is a low level image api that is probably called by `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` or `draw`.

How do I get rid of these errors ?

Comment: Did you figure this out -- I'm having same issue...

Comment: I have the same problem! Any solutions?